# CSharpCompilation with Roslyn in separate AppDomain with GlobalsType

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm trying to run custom C# code in a separate AppDomain with restricted permissions with a globals type which should be resolved in the script. For example,

```
public class Global {
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

With my script being..

```
return Name;
```

should return the value of Name.

This is easily done with Roslyn but turns out Roslyn demands an Unrestricted PermissionSet to compile and execute scripts so I can't just do CSharpScript.Evaluate(...)

So I'm hoping to compile the script into a byte array using

```
CSharpCompilation.CreateScriptCompilation("foo", 
    syntaxTree: CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(script, ..), 
    globalsType: typeof(Global), ...)
```

which I've successfully done. I'm able to invoke a simple script like (return "abc";) using reflection, however I'm stuck on how I can pass an instance of my Global object so that it can be resolved upon execution.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Perhaps compile in the primary AppDomain but execute in the restricted AppDomain.

Comment: I've been battling with this for a week, and I came up with the following: https://github.com/Sodoshi/RoslynTest